# JS: Add +1 to variable when check 1 of checkboxes in a group (show tooltip)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tooltip

I have a form with radiobuttons, checkboxes and textfields.
For example,
Group 1 includes radiobuttons.

```
<ul class="radios">
    <li><input id="const-style" class="radio-form"  type="radio" name="material" value="w1" /><span>test</span></li>
    <li><input id="const-style" class="radio-form"  type="radio" name="material" value="w2" /><span>test2</span></li>
    <li><input id="const-style" class="radio-form"  type="radio" name="material" value="w3" /><span>test3</span></li>  
    ...      
</ul>
```

Group 2 includes checkboxes.

```
<ul class="checks">                                               
    <li><input id="const-style1" class="checkbox-form"  type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="ch1" />ch1</li>
    <li><input id="const-style2" class="checkbox-form"  type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="ch2" />ch2</li>
    <li><input id="const-style3" class="checkbox-form"  type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="ch3" />ch3</li>   
    ...    
</ul>
```

Group 3 with textfields (Name, Surname, Email).

```
<ul class="form-info">  
    <li><input id="name" class="text inline" type="Name" name="name" size="25" placeholder="Name" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/></li>
    <li><input id="SurName" class="text inline" type="SurName" name="surname" size="25" placeholder="Surname" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/></li>
    <li><input id="email" class="text inline" type="Email" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/></li>
</ul>
```

When a user click at least 1 checkbox or radiobutton or feel a textfield, a script adds +1 to variable (**1 point maximum** on a hole group) and after that it should show a tooltip with this counter (anywhere). If he/she uncheck his/her choice (and a group with checkboxes or textfields or radiobuttons become unchecked) it should subtruct 1 point.

How to do that with JS or Jquery?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Something like this? https://jsbin.com/waluyicapa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Yes! That's it! Much thanks to you!

Comment: I made it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the fiddle https://jsbin.com/waluyicapa/edit?html,js,console,output.

HTML

```
  <ul class="radios form-group" is-filled="false">
    <li><input id="const-style" class="radio-form"  type="radio" name="material" value="w1" /><span>test</span></li>
    <li><input id="const-style" class="radio-form"  type="radio" name="material" value="w2" /><span>test2</span></li>
    <li><input id="const-style" class="radio-form"  type="radio" name="material" value="w3" /><span>test3</span></li>  
    ...      
</ul>

<ul class="checks form-group" is-filled="false" >                                               
    <li><input id="const-style1" class="checkbox-form"  type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="ch1" />ch1</li>
    <li><input id="const-style2" class="checkbox-form"  type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="ch2" />ch2</li>
    <li><input id="const-style3" class="checkbox-form"  type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="ch3" />ch3</li>   
    ...    
</ul>

  <ul class="form-info form-group" is-filled="false">  
    <li><input id="name" class="text inline" type="Name" name="name" size="25" placeholder="Name" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/></li>
    <li><input id="SurName" class="text inline" type="SurName" name="surname" size="25" placeholder="Surname" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/></li>
    <li><input id="email" class="text inline" type="Email" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/></li>
</ul> 

  <p id ="count">
    </p>
```

JS

```
$('.form-group').on('change',':input',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $group = $this.closest('.form-group'); 



  $group.attr('is-filled',!!($group.find('input').filter(':checked').length) );

  var $text_inputs = $group.find('.text');

  if(!$text_inputs.length){
    return void(0);
  }

  var count = 0;

  $.each($text_inputs,function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    if($that.val() && $.trim($that.val()).length ){
      count++;
    }

  });  

  $group.attr('is-filled',!!(count) );  
});

$('.form-group').on('change',':input',updateCount);




function updateCount(){
  $('#count').html('Current Count = ' + $('.form-group[is-filled="true"]').length);

}
```